# 1998 Plymouth Voyager

Tags: oil

The oil pressure cluster light is coming on and the chime sound as well,the oil level seems fine.

Wondering what the problem may be?

The 1998 voyager has 138,000 miles and next oil change is not due yet?

Comment: could be a faulty oil pressure switch, or get an oil change anyway

Comment: Light comes on when oil pressure gets below 5psi (IIRC). Does the light stay on steady, or does it flicker, then possibly go out when you rev the engine? What kind of oil filter do you use?